# How do you pass syscall.Errno to os.Exit?

Tags: go, system-calls

Let's say I try to acquire a lock, fail, and want to exit the program.

```
err = syscall.Flock(lockfd, syscall.LOCK_EX|syscall.LOCK_NB)
if err == syscall.EAGAIN {
    os.Exit(err)
}
```

The problem is you need to pass an integer to os.Exit.

I've tried:

```
os.Exit(int(err))
os.Exit(syscall.EAGAIN)

// Compiles fine, but the cast fails.. no idea why
eerr, _ := err.(*syscall.Errno); os.Exit(int(*eerr)) 

// panics
reflect.ValueOf(err).Int()
```

It seems like you can compare the syscall.Errno to other integers, but actually trying to get the value of it is escaping me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can normally just convert a `syscall.Errno` to an int

```
if err == syscall.EAGAIN {
    os.Exit(int(err))
}
```

[`syscall.Errno`](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Errno) is defined as a `uintptr`, which can be converted directly to an `int`. There's no interface, assertion, or reflection involved.

But when receiving it as an `error` interface, you need to assert it first.

```
if err == syscall.EAGAIN {
    os.Exit(int(err.(syscall.Errno)))
}
```

The `syscall.Errno` is used as a value, not a pointer, no need to try and dereference it with `*`.

Comment: As I explained in the question, I tried converting to an int, and I get the compile time error `cannot convert err (type error) to type int`

Comment: Also note that this is in the `syscall` package which can have different definitions on different operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

**Don't use `errno` values as exit codes.**

Exit values and `errno` values may both be integers, but they otherwise have nothing in common.

In particular, `EPERM` is often (always?) "1" but shells often handle/expect that an exit code of one is "alternate success" rather than failure (for example, when `grep` doesn't find a match).

An additional example,
the [sysexits(3) manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE&format=html)
for the BSDs define some values for use with `exit`.

However, Go (being more OS agnostic) doesn't use these.
E.g. the flag package exits with "2" instead of "64" (`EX_USAGE`) as recommended by BSD. (Note, on BSD 64 as an errno value is `EHOSTDOWN`).